# PHP Thumbnail Class

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, thumbnails

I am looking for a solid PHP thumbnail generating class. Does anyone know any good ones that are open-source?

I could write one, but I really don't want to. The one thing I hate most about PHP is manipulating images with GD and Imagemagick.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it even possible to do it without these tools? - http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/splittingred/phpThumbOf
- http://ria-coder.com/blog/php-thumbnail-generator Maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [phpThumb()](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/). Its a script that internally uses GD library and/or ImageMagick (whichever is available and whichever it thinks is best for the job) to perform basic image manipulation tasks, including thumbnail generation and square thumbnail generation.

You can use it like this:

```
<!-- best fit -->
<img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/path/to/image.jpg&w=64&h=64">
<!-- crop fit (square thumbnails) -->
<img src="/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/path/to/image.jpg&w=64&h=64&zc=1">
```

It has built in caching engine so second time a browser requests the above image it is served from its own cache instead of re-generating the thumbnail every time. Though, you may want to spend an hour or so configuring it.

Comment: I can also recommend phpThumb. I've used it in a project and was quite impressed by it. You can also use it to create thumbnails within your PHP scripts, after uploading a file, for example. It is also well-documented and has good error-handling.

Comment: The site I am going to be working with is some what of a high traffic site. These images will be viewed thousands of times a day. In your opinion, will phpThumbs cache functionality work well in this situation?

Comment: I've used it on moderate traffic websites where it performed very well. I cannot say how it will perform under high traffic, but do look at the configuration file in detail. You can tweak cache settings, disable the options that you do not need and configure phpThumb to prefer ImageMagick over GD.

Answer (score 4):

use `class.upload.php`

see this link for details may be its help you more

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

Answer (score 0):

Generating a thumbnail requires so little code that it is a "simple example" of the GD library's resizing functions in the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Just copy and paste.